# Want to store last paragraph to any variable

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I have [long text](http://dpaste.com/648868/). And I'm converting this string to dict.

Here is code

```
data_dict = {}    
filter_dict = {}    
for each in text.split("\n"):
    temp = each.split('=')
    if len(temp) == 2:
        data_dict[temp[0]] = temp[1]
data = dict((k.strip(), v.strip()) for k, v in data_dict.iteritems())
```

Here is output which is convert from text to dict

```
 {'producer': 'Sailadhar Baruah', 
'image': 'paporithefilm.jpg', 
'distributor': '', 
'alt': '',
 'image size': '',
 'gross': '', 
 'writer': 'Jahnu Barua',
 'cinematography': 'Binod Pradhan', 
 'music': 'Satya Baruah P. P. Vidyanathan',
 'followed by': '', 
 'narrator': '', 
 'director': 'Jahnu Barua', 
 'released': '1986',
 'studio': 'Dolphin s Pvt. Ltd',
 'starring': 'Gopi Desai Biju Phukan Sushil Goswami Chetana Das Dulal Roy',
 'editing': '', 
 'name': 'Papori', 
 'language': 'Assamese languageAssamese', 
 'country': 'Assam, IND', 'budget': '', 
 'caption': 'A Screenshot',
 'preceded by': '', 
 'runtime': '144 minutes'}
```

I just want to know where is my last paragraph gone? Can I store last paragraph text to any varible? thanks

Comment: Your last paragraph doesn't have a `key = value` format like you are expecting... or, is the last paragraph supposed to ve the value for `followed by`?

Comment: The text you were trying to parse: Is it in plain text or in XML? On dpaste link you provided, it's saying that the syntax is XML.

Comment: @sberry2A Last paragraph is not value for followed by. This is separate string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out, you are only matching when you have a `key = value` format.  Try something like this instead.

```
text = file("text.txt", "r").readlines()

skip_keys = ('film', '')
data_dict = {}
for each in text:
    temp = [x.strip() for x in each.split('=')]
    if temp[0] in skip_keys:
        continue
    if len(temp) == 2:
        data_dict[temp[0]] = temp[1]
    else:
        data_dict['no_key'] = temp[0]
print data_dict
```

Here, your paragraph will be added to 'no_key'.  I started out my answer using a defaultdict from the collections module, and setting the value to be lists so you could track any unkeyed values, but, if your format is consistent, then the above should work.

Answer (score 1):

You are not storing the text at the bottom.  The only place where you assign values to the dictionary entries is under the if len(temp) == 2.  Since that text paragraph doesn't have an equal sign, this part will simply fall through and nothing will be done.  You need an 'else' somewhere there